# Search and replace by using the searched pattern using wild card in vi

Tags: regex, vim

I have below lines in a file:

```
HELLO(qwqwq)
My name ()
Your name ()
HELLO(dsdasd)
HELLO(sdsdsdasdasdasf)
```

I want it to be replaced as follows:

```
qwqwq:
My name ()
Your name ()
dsdasd:
sdsdsdasdasdasf:
```

Here I have a pattern `HELLO(.*)` that can be used in a search and replace command but how to do it in vim ?

Comment: it's easy with awk or sed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line will help you for the given example:

```
%s/\vHELLO\(([^)]*).*/\1:/
```

With `:g` and `normal` command is also easy:

```
:g/HELLO/norm! %yi(VpA:
```

Comment: %s/\vHELLO\(([^)]*).*/\1:/

@Kent This worked. Thanks a lot. Can you please explain what happens here? I got confused with so many slashes and brackets as I am pretty new to complex regex.

Comment: @MalavShelat it is not complex.  I suggest you read vim's doc about regex. If you don't know much about regex, read some tutorial first. here `\v` is "very magic" mode, `:h magic` to see details.

Comment: Thanks. Will do so.

Answer (score 0):

First, make a search (I opted to not use very magic mode) 
because either way, I have to use escape "\" using very magic or not, 
it only changes the place I have to use it.

```
/HELLO(\([^)]*\))
( ..................... regular parenthesis 
\( .................... start group 1
[^)]* ................. denies everything until \) closing group 1
\)  ................... close group 1
) ..................... regular parenthesis
```

Once you have tested your search pattern you can use it in your search, 
here I am using another separator instead slash. Omitting the search pattern will make vim use the previous search as the pattern.

```
%s,,\1,g
```

I like this approach because is safer, before making any change we can test with a search